# Flutter add object to list of objects

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a model called `RecipeModel` which basically has details about recipes(recipeName, recipeAuthor etc).

Now I want the users to mark any recipe as favorite which will basically be a List of RecipeModel.

Here's my `FavoriteRecipeModel`:

```
class FavoriteRecipeModel {
  List<RecipeModel>? recipeList;
  FavoriteRecipeModel({this.recipeList});
  factory FavoriteRecipeModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      FavoriteRecipeModel(
        recipeList: json["recipeList"] == null ? null : json["recipeList"],
      );
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "recipe": recipeList == null ? null : recipeList,
      };
}
```

And here's how I intend to use it in my recipe_details_screen:

```
class RecipeDetailsScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final RecipeModel? recipe;

  RecipeDetailsScreen({required this.recipe});

  @override
  _RecipeDetailsScreenState createState() => _RecipeDetailsScreenState();
}

class _RecipeDetailsScreenState extends State<RecipeDetailsScreen> {
  FavoriteRecipeModel favoriteRecipeList = FavoriteRecipeModel();
  void addToFavorites() {
    favoriteRecipeList.recipeList!.add(widget.recipe!);
  }
  ......some other widgets
}
```

problem is whenever I'm trying to call the `addToFavorites` method I'm getting this error:

```
Null check operator used on a null value
```

My plan is to add the recipeModel that has been passed to this page to a list and then save the list in local storage using Hive in a json file.

But I don't understand how to solve the error.

**Update 1:**

I changed my model to

`List<RecipeModel>? recipeList = [];`

and inside my details_screen:

`FavoriteRecipeModel favoriteRecipeList = FavoriteRecipeModel(); favoriteRecipeList.recipeList!.add(widget.recipe!);`

But still getting the null check error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to add values ​​to a list that does not exist.

```
List<RecipeModel>? recipeList;
```

when you call:

```
favoriteRecipeList.recipeList!.add(widget.recipe!);
```

the recipeList is not initialized.

You can make it empty by default:

```
List<RecipeModel>? recipeList = [];
```

Or pass an empty list when instantiating the class:

```
List<RecipeModel> emptyList = [];
FavoriteRecipeModel favoriteRecipeList = FavoriteRecipeModel(emptyList);
```

Comment: so I have to do it inside the model and everything will be same inside the `recipe_details_screen`?

Comment: @FahimHoque One way or another, the list variable needs to be initialized (i.e. actually contain a list) before you can add stuff to it. It doesn't really matter where or how you do it as long as you can guarantee the variable isn't null by the time something tries to add to it.

Comment: @FahimHoque yes, just make your list empty be default: List<RecipeModel>? recipeList = [];

Comment: I tried `List<RecipeModel>? recipeList = [];` inside model and `favoriteRecipeList.recipeList!.add(widget.recipe!);` inside the details_screen but still getting the `null check operator used on a null value`